# Delete lines with matching pattern after the first line with sed

Tags: sed

I would like to delete every line that contains a pattern after the first line (the pattern is `/^country\t/`). I can delete *every* occurrence with `sed '/^country\t/d' in.txt > out.txt`, but I would like to keep the first occurrence on the first line.

The back story is that I have a directory of tab-delimited files with headers and I concatenate these files with `cat`. I would like to remove the extra headers.

In Vim I could do something like `: 2,$g/^country\t/d`, but I can't figure out the sed solution. When I try `sed '2,$ /^country\t/d in.txt > out.txt` I get the error `unknown command: /`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct way but this is a workaround:

```
sed -e '1,2 s/^country\t/NOCHANGE/' -e '/^country\t/d' -e 's/NOCHANGE/country/'  in.txt > out.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
sed '1b;/^country\t/d' in.txt > out.txt
```

or

```
sed '1!{/^country\t/d}' in.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: Both suggestions work perfectly. I prefer the 2nd one because `!` is a well known negation parameter

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/pattern/{x;/pattern/!{x;h;b;};x;d}' file
```

This will delete every matching line AFTER the first matching line. Commentary:

> **/pattern/** - match pattern
>
> **{x** - if above is matched, swap pattern and hold buffer
>
> **;/pattern/!{x;h;b;}** - now test the pattern buffer (it will now be
>   empty on the FIRST match) and if does not ! already contain pattern
>   then swap 'x' the pattern and hold buffer back again, then COPY the
>   pattern buffer into the hold buffer 'h', and branch 'b' to the end of
>   the script, and load the next line.
>
> **;x;d}** - this bit only gets executed if the negated pattern match in
>   the previous step fails - i.e. the pattern buffer matches your
>   pattern. In this case, swap the hold and pattern buffer back again
>   'x', and delete 'd' the line.

Comment: Trying this, I get: `sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched '{'`

Comment: For me this was the real solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/[^country]*//2' <old >new
```

This should change all the instances of country except for the first one (if you have two on the first line only the first one will be preserved).

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to delete the whole line. Is my only choice using the `s///g` construct and making the pattern something like `/^country.*\n/`?

Comment: Check this out: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Comment: +1, good link! (I had found that in my searches, but couldn't piece together @johnshen64's hack.)

Answer (score 0):

if the /pattern/ does not match an empty line, then using "the `hold` space is initialized as empty line" to test the first match one:

preserve the first line:

`sed '/pattern/ {x; /^$/!d; g;}' file`

drop the first line:

`sed '/pattern/ x' file`

only edit the first line:

`sed '/pattern/ {x; /^$/!b'$'\n'' g; s/pattern/xx/; }' file`

only edit the following line:

`sed '/pattern/ {x; s/pattern/xx/; t'$'\n'' g; }' file`

PS: `$'\n'` (not a `;`) follows `t` or `b`, making bsd sed happy.